# How can I restrict android app developer to send form to my database which i send same from php page?

Tags: php

How can I restrict android app developer to send form to my database, which i send same from php page? I do not want any app developer send data to my database? What type of functionality I have to write to Know whether php form submit to db and app developer form not submitted?

Comment: Password restrict your site/form?

Comment: Need to add some custom checks like flag/password/authorization etc. to prevent.

Comment: You can create two database users, one with write privilege and other with readonly privilege. Give app developer the readonly privileged db user login.

Comment: When you say "database" do you really mean your database server or do you mean a public-facing HTTP endpoint (e.g. a URL handled by PHP with PHP code that inserts data from the request into the database)?

Answer (score 0):

Mobile apps would be running on different mobiles and hence would be having different IP addresses. 
You need to ensure that your database accepts a connection request from specific IP addresses only. Most probably it should be localhost.

Comment: Assuming you are using MySQL. You can create user using below SQL.

CREATE USER 'username'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';

Such user would be able to connect to MySQL only if connect is requested from same machine on which MySQL runs. So any user trying to access MySQL from different IP would not be able to connect.

Comment: I am getting your point but my (php)form data will be submited from all machine accept android app what can i do for that

Comment: I need functionality that android app not able to submit that form and website or any computer can able to submit that form

Comment: Assuming a scenario where web form is on different URL and there is a separate script to process the data when form is submitted.  In this case when web form page is rendered you can generate a random string and save it in PHP session and also put this in hidden field in the web form. When web form is submitted in the PHP script you can compare the random string with that of the value saved in session. Or you can use captach code.

Comment: On the other hand the android app would be submitting data directly to the script that processes it so in absence of the random string you can decide not to process data. To another extreme you would need to detect if the hit is being received from mobile app by scanning request headers.